# Excel Macro to create hyper link - not working

Tags: vba, excel

Hi all im trying to create a macro to do the following:

Create a work sheet Create a master list of work sheets created with a hyper link to each one.

I have tried to automate this process with a macro as follows:

```
  Sheets("MasterSheet").Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
Sheets("MasterSheet (2)").Name = Sheets("setup project").Range("c4").Text
Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = Sheets("setup project").Range("c4").Text
Range("C3").FormulaR1C1 = Sheets("setup project").Range("d4").Text
Dim sheetname As Worksheet
sheetname = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
Dim targetsheet As Range
targetsheet = ActiveSheet.Range("c4")
Sheets("project overview").Hyperlinks.add Anchor:=Sheets("project overview").Range("B6"), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "'" & sheetname & "'!" & targetsheet.Address, TextToDisplay:=Sheets("setup project").Range("c4").Text
```

Unfortunatley I this is not working and I am unable to a) get the the hyperlink to work or reference to the sheet I have just created. B) I am unable to use the name of the sheet created for the hyper link name. Any help would be much appreciated!

Kind Regards

L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Objects` to refer to your `Worksheets` and specify the `WS`for `.Range, .Cells etc`, assigning has to be with `Set` for objects. Like:

```
Sub Test()
Dim nWs as Worksheet, sPro as Worksheet, oPro as Worksheet
Set sPro = Worksheets("setup project")
Set oPro = Worksheets("project overview")
Sheets("MasterSheet").Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
Set nWs = Worksheets(1)
With nWs 
  .Name =sPro.Range("C4").Value
  .Range("C2").Value = .Name
  .Range("C3").Value = sPro.Range("D4").Value
End With
oPro.Hyperlinks.add Anchor:= oPro.Range("B6"), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "'" & nWs.Name & "'!C4", TextToDisplay:= nWs.Name
End Sub
```

You should consider searching before asking questions. There is a microsoft documentation for Excel VBA that should help you with the syntax problems.

Comment: thank you UGP for taking the time to provide the above response. I have tried a few ideas on here but yet to find one that has worked for me. The above code has also failed to work unfortunately, I get the error 'Method 'Name' of object'_Worksheet' failed'

Comment: This Code works. You should probaly check the spelling of the `Worksheet`-Names in the code, i used the ones the provided, but there has to be a difference to the once in your workbook.

Comment: UGP there is no difference, I have checked

Comment: You should always say in which line the error happened, but i guess its here  `.Name = sPro.Range("C4")`when i look at the error message. that means it cannot rename the sheet it created, because there is already a sheet with that name.

Comment: that does not help in anyway to solve your problem. you should be more specific. i forgot the `'` in the hyperlink, but that does not explain the error you got. the only options that you happen if `Worksheets("setup project").Range("C4").Value` is empty or there is already a `Worksheet` with this name.

Comment: you are right it is the line .Name, it works other than naming itself.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code:

```
    Dim sheetname As Worksheet
    Dim targetsheet As Range

    Sheets("MasterSheet").Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
    Sheets("MasterSheet (2)").Name = Sheets("setup project").Range("c4").Text
    Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = Sheets("setup project").Range("c4").Text
    Range("C3").FormulaR1C1 = Sheets("setup project").Range("d4").Text


    Set sheetname = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)

    Set targetsheet = ActiveSheet.Range("c4")        
    Sheets("project overview").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("project overview").Range("B6"), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "'" & sheetname.Name & "'!" & targetsheet.Address, TextToDisplay:=Sheets("setup project").Range("c4").Text
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I have tested it actually.